# Can't figure out what this line does

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Can someone please tell me what does this line do:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("AH1").FormulaArray = "=iferror(MATCH(1,(plan!T3:T20000=AF1)*
  (plan!W3:W20000=MONTH(E1)),0),0)+2"
```

plan is a name of sheet in my Excel file. thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking what the line of VBA code does? (inserts a formula) or what the equation it inserts into `Cell AH1` does?

Comment: What the equation it inserts into Cell AH1 does?

Comment: Hello, 2 answers posted below. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula is a doing a multi-criteria CountIF. Without seeing the data, it is doing the following. 
Count the data in `column T` if any of the rows match what is in cell `AF1`, but only count it if the corresponding month shown in `Column W` matches the `Month` shown in cell `E1`. Then `add 2`.

Answer (score 0):

this add array formula (usually inserted with Ctrl+Shift+Enter) to the cell AH1. It seems that formula checks if value in column T in plan sheet is equal to this one in AF column and month of date in E column equals to value in plan!W column, plus 2 for some reason.